# Nomenclature: two row columns for a part

Tags: multicol, nomenclature

I am trying to create a nomenclature. I have 5 groups (A to E). I want to show only group C in two columns. The rest is fine. Is there a chance with package normenclature and multicol?

```
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.15\hsize} 
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1] {%
    \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1][]{##1}
    \item[~] %Platz oben
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{\item[\textbf {\large Griechische 
            Zeichen}] }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{\large Lateinische 
                Zeichen}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{D}}{\item[\setlength{\columnsep}{48pt}\textbf{\large Abkürzungen}]}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\item[\textbf{\large Indizes}]} {%
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{E}}{\item[\textbf{\large Dimensionslose Kennzahlen}]}{}}}}}
    
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}
\makenomenclature
```

This is the code I used to define the 5 groups.  There are like 120 entries in total. However group C includes 20 shortcuts like indices. I would like to write them in 2 columns. The other groups should stay in one column.

As far as I tried, always the whole document changed or put the groups in a strange way.
I would be very thankful for your help!
Thank you!